# How does sender.selected = ! sender.selected toggle between selected states?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, toggle

I'm very new to Objective-C so sorry if this is extremely obvious to many of you, but I'm trying to work out how the following piece of code is actually working:

```
- (IBAction)chooseColour:(UIButton *)sender {
 sender.selected = !sender.isSelected;
}
```

Now it obviously toggles between the selected and unselected states of the button sending the action, but what is the code 'sender.selected = !sender.isSelected' actually saying? Is it just 'set the sender selected property to the opposite (i.e. ! not) of the getter'? So if the getter is 'getting' the current selected value as true then it sets the selected property as !true i.e false. Or is this a piece of convenience code that I'm not yet privy to? Because it also seems that '!sender.isSelected' simply means not selected as in

```
if (!sender.isSelected){
statement
}
```

i.e. do statement if the sender is not selected. This is no doubt really obvious, just I'm a bit confused with it at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: I *almost* downvoted, but then I noticed that you took the time and made the effort **thinking logically.** Good job! :) (You can't imagine how many beginners asking on SO don't...)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! I'm finding that lots of the guide books give you the code and tell you what it does without really explaining it, so I'm just making sure I understand what it is actually saying. Lots of it becomes obvious if after a few minutes thinking it through, quite a learning curve though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are entirely correct, it's calling the getter to obtain the value and calling the setter with the NOT (`!`) of the value. It isn't Objective-C, it's plain C syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I probably should have said that I am new to programming in general, which is why I'm not too clear on the C/obj-C borderline, but I will get there eventually.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it just 'set the sender selected property to the opposite (i.e. ! not) of the getter'?

Exactly. That.

> Or is this a piece of convenience code that I'm not yet privy to?

No, the only piece of syntactic sugar is the dot notation for getters/setters, but you are already aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

The portion of the code:

```
sender.selected = !sender.isSelected;
```

Basically inverts the selection. It asks the question `Is this false?` so true evaluates false, and false evaluates to true. So it's a toggle.

Comment: That seems like an easy way to think of it actually, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

from documentation :

```
@property(nonatomic,getter=isSelected) BOOL selected;                                // default is NO may be used by some subclasses or by application
```

//explanation
if you use ![sender isSelected] value in property isn't changed. then if you use setter sender.selected = ![sender isSelected] - new value is set to the sender (selected property). then run getter sender isSelected return new value, uff i hope it helps

Comment: Yeah I read that in the documentation, I realise that isSelected is the getter, but it still wasn't obvious what the code I am interested in was actually doing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you use ![sender isSelected] value in property isn't changed. then if you use setter sender.selected = ![sender isSelected] - new value is set to the sender (selected property). then run getter sender isSelected return new value, uff i hope it helps