# What is sender.selected = !sender.isSelected actually doing to cause my button to toggle?

Tags: objective-c, c

Currently learning objetive-c. Gone through various books and also some tutorials on the lynda website and have now found the Stanford course which I think suits my style of learning. I've been watching the first 3 lectures over and over again basically doing it until I'm 100% with what has been taught and I'm not far.

I'm having a hard time understanding what the following code is doing and how it causes my button to toggle.

```
sender.selected = !sender.isSelected
```

I would prefer to use:

```
if (sender.selected) 
{
  sender.selected = NO;
} else {
  sender.selected = YES;
}
```

Why? because it makes sense to me and is obvious what is going on as I've used if statements in plenty of other programming languages in the past. I can actually do the first assignment with no issue and understand what is going on in most of it but when ever i delete my code and retype to practice this one part of it trips me up and I feel like I'm cheating myself moving forward without truly understanding what is going on.

I done some googling and came accross this post: [How does sender.selected = ! sender.selected toggle between selected states?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243921/how-does-sender-selected-sender-selected-toggle-between-selected-states)

It feels like sparks are flying in my head when I read through but just not enough to ignite that "ah hah I get it now" fire.

Let's say the button is selected before I tap/click my button I under stand that it's state will be set to not selected (= !sender.isSelected) but now let's say it isn't selected and I tap/click on my button. How is it being set to selected?

I feel there is someone out there who can explain it in a way that will make sense to me. I know once it's in my head it'll stay there forever. I've been sitting down here for a few hours trying to think it through. Fallen asleep a few times and decided that help is needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `isSelected` returns the current state.  `!` inverts that state.  Assigning to `selected` sets the state.  Simple.  (Though you can certainly use the `if` statement if you prefer -- it has the advantage of being less cryptic.)

Comment: You take the state and negate it. False + negate = true. True + negate = false.

Comment: (Note that for Objective-C properties that are BOOLs the "getter" method is generally named "is<WhateverPropertyName>" rather than simply "<whateverPropertyName>".  Which is why you see `isSelected` on the right side instead of `selected`.)

Comment: The ! operator toggles the boolean value. It can also be used on integers. True means different than zero, false means zero. If you negate every number different from zero you obtain zero, if you negate zero you obtain one.

Comment: So for example the buttons is selected....  "!sender.isSelected" is first checking if the buttons state is selected, and it is so now because of the "!" it makes the state unselected/NO/false/opposite of what ever it is and sets the value of the setters selected state to that state? Vica versa?

Comment: @HotLicks, dot syntax should use the name of the property, not the getter. Using the getter name happens to work by "accident".

Comment: @KenThomases - What you "should use" for referencing properties seems to change with every new Xcode release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lack of comfort may stem from a common challenge when people learn programming, moving from the familiarity of just numbers to the many *types* used in programming. In brief a type is a set of *values* along with a number of *relations* which take one or more values from the set and produce another value in the set. In the real world these sets can be infinite - there are is an infinite number of whole numbers - but in programming languages the are (usually) finite.

Now integers, aka whole numbers, are a set whose values are the familiar numbers and the basic operations are add, subtract, multiply, negate, etc. In (Objective-)C there are multiple integral types - different sets with differing numbers of members; e.g. `int`, `unsigned long`. Using this familiar type do you feel comfortable with the following:

```
int x; // declare a variable which holds a value of type int
int y; // and another one

...; // other stuff

y = -x; // place in y the negation of the value in x
```

You undoubtedly feel comfortable, it's just arithmetic which you've probably been doing for years! In set language the negation relation maps one member of the int set to another.

Now programming languages deal with many more types than just whole numbers, but the underlying concept is the same for all of them - a set with a collection of basic relations.

The *boolean* type is central to most programming languages. It is a set with just two members; *true* and *false*; and basic relations *and*, *or* and *not*. The not relation maps true to false and false to true.

In Objective-C the boolean type is called `BOOL`, `YES` is used for true, `NO` for false, and the basic relations are `&&` (and), `||` (or) and `!` (not). So now consider:

```
BOOL x; // declare a variable which holds a value of type BOOL
BOOL y; // and another one

...; // other stuff

y = !x; // place in y the "not" of the value in x
```

The similarity to the integer case above is obvious - its all just sets and relations.

Based on this it should be clear that:

```
sender.selected = !sender.isSelected
```

is better than:

```
if (sender.selected) 
{
   sender.selected = NO;
} 
else
{
   sender.selected = YES;
}
```

The latter uses a control statement (`if`) to do what is really the equivalent of basic arithmetic.

Booleans, integers, floating-point numbers, characters, etc. are all just types, treat them similarly - you'll write better code.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. // place in y the "not" of the value in x clarifies my comment above. It took me a while to get it but it now makes sense. I always thought the !something part of code was read in one go if that makes sense. I now look at it as 2 parts. First get the something then e.g. true and then make the value the opposite of that something. Didn't realise the complier read that part of the code first.

Comment: Read your answer again. Now it really makes sense. The sender.selected = !sender.isSelected thing is the same as a =+ b, c =* d etc. I know if I saw sender.selected =! sender.isSelected I wouldn't even have needed to post this question simply because of the placement of the exclamation mark. I got there in the end but really can't believe I missed that. Embarassing.

Comment: @LondonGuy - Not exactly, `a = !b` is like `a = -b` which is not the same as `a =- b` - the former are monadic operators (not, negate resp.) while the latter is shorthand for a dyadic operator (subtract, `a = a - b`).

Comment: I guess I have some reading to do. Atleast for now I can that I understand what is happening with sender.selected = !sender.isSelected.

Comment: @LondonGuy - apologies typo in above comment, the compound operator is `-=` not `=-`.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use:

```
 if (sender.isSelected)
   sender.selected = false;
 else
   sender.selected = true;
```

It's just that it's shorter to write `sender.selected = !sender.isSelected`, and it makes it clearer to the compiler what you want to have happen. And the compiler MAY generate more complex code for the longer form, which is of no benefit.

It's probably worth getting used to "short form" of writing this sort of thing if you intend on using C or C++, because this sort of "trick" is quite commonly used.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly why I decided to keep thinking and not move on. At first when I looked at objective-c I thought WTF never. Now I prefer it. I find myself looking forward to coming home from work just to put in practice. One thing I've learnt from learning other programming languages is to take my time and not to deceive myself and to make sure I understand something before moving forward. I feel the only reason I prefer the if statement is because I understand it. Once I understand the other way of writing it I'd probably prefer that way.

Comment: @LondonGuy: Just bear in mind that there are different styles, and there's nothing WRONG with writing more "length" code as such. It is a balance. It is at least as important to write clear and understandable code as it is to write "short" code. Being clever, and squeezing three lines into one line can often make the code harder to read, so it's not a desirable thing. However, this particular trick is common enough that you should probably just accept that it's the short way of writing the longer form.